# Wordpress theme not working optimally with WP Rocket with IOS mobiles

Tags: javascript, ios, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello so we are using Tagdiv's Newspaper Theme on our Wordpress website. We are using WP Rocket as the caching plugin.

There is a feature "Delay JS Execution" in WP Rocket, that when activated, is showing a bug in the IOS mobile phone devices.

Every link, especially the hamburger icon menu button has to be tapped twice for the menu to appear. However if I scroll down the page, & then tap the menu button it works. So there is a JS file(s) that's loaded or delayed?

WP Rocket has an "Exclude JS file" section where we can exclude specific JS scripts that shouldn't be "delayed" So perhaps a file needs to be excluded?

Can anyone help me with this? What more JS scripts need to be excluded if any? I hope my question is acceptable here. Thank you.